# FreeBSD: usernames longer than 16 chars

Tags: freebsd

Can someone give me the complete process to change FreeBSD from a 16 char max to 64 char max on unsername length?

Essentially this is to add some support for Virtualmin/Webmin.

Inspired from http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=1447 I tried the following:

Changed in `/usr/src/sys/sys/param.h`

```
#define MAXLOGNAME      65              /* max login name length (incl. NUL) */
```

Changed in `/usr/src/include/utmp.h`

```
#define UT_NAMESIZE     64      /* see MAXLOGNAME in <sys/param.h> */
```

Ran

```
# cd /usr/src
# make buildworld
```

And now

```
# adduser
```

Still reports too long username!?

Comment: Btw. its FreeBSD 8.1

Comment: 33 characters in current HEAD in param.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install world:

```
# make installworld
```

Comment: Ahh... OK :) thx!